# How to make superclass in Python work as a factory?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, initialization

I have similar classes `Class[ABC]` that may have different `__init__` parameters.
The all inherit from a `SuperClass`, which I would also like to work as a factory:

```py
class SuperClass():
  valid_subtypes = {}
    # 'a': ClassA, 'b': ClassB, 'c': ClassC
    # need to set it empty, as subclasses havent been defined. 
  
  def __new__(cls, subtype=None, *args, **kwargs):  # The Factory. 
    if cls is not SuperClass: 
      args = (subtype, *args)
      return object.__new__(cls)
    
    if subtype in cls.valid_subtypes: 
      subclass = cls.valid_subtypes[subtype]
      return object.__new__(subclass)


class ClassA(SuperClass): 
  pass


class ClassB(SuperClass):
  def __init__(self, pb): 
    self.pb = pb

class ClassC(SuperClass): 
  def __init__(self, pc1, pc2): 
    self.pc1 = pc1
    self.pc2 = pc2

the_classes = {'a': ClassA, 'b': ClassB, 'c': ClassC}
SuperClass.valid_subtypes.update(the_classes)
```

The previous code allows one to create subclasses and inherit from `SuperClass`:

```py
a1_obj = ClassA()
b1_obj = ClassB('hello b')
c1_obj = ClassC('hello c', 1)
```

But it's gonna fail when using the `__new__` factory.

```py
a2_obj = SuperClass('a')
b2_obj = SuperClass('b', pb ='hello b')
c2_obj = SuperClass('c', pc1='hello c', pc2=1)
```

While the `__new__` method seems to return the right object.
I understand that `__init__()` is then called with the initiating parameters which don't match its instance.

```py
a1_obj.__init__('a')  # corresponding to ClassA.__init__(a1_obj, 'a')
b2_obj.__init__('b', 'hello b')
c2_obj.__init__('c', 'hello c', 1)
```

I have tried modifying `SuperClass.__init__(self, subtype, *args, **kwargs)` to account for the `subtype`, that is:

```py
def __init__(self, subtype, *args, **kwargs): 
  if subtype in valid_subtypes: 
    valid_subtypes[subtype].__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

This doesn't seem to get called as the created objects by `__new__` are of class `Class[ABC]`.

- How do the `__init__` and `__new__` work with this strange inheritance?
- Could these two initialization calls be made to work at the same time?
- ... without modifying the proper subclasses, but only the factory `SuperClass`?
- or Would I necessarily need an extra method, eg. `@classmethod` `SuperClass.create()` or class that separates from the super-class from which they inherit?

Thank you for your help.
Regards from Mexico.

PS. One solution that seems okay, albeit not super ideal, is to name all the parameters upon creation:

```py
a2_obj = SuperClass(subtype='a')
b2_obj = SuperClass(subtype='b', pb ='hello b')
c2_obj = SuperClass(subtype='c', pc1='hello c', pc2='1')
```

Comment: `SuperClass.__new__` should be reserved for actually creating instances for its subclasses via `super().__new__`. Use a dedicated class method (or regular function) as the factory function.

Comment: @chepner That makes sense, thanks.  Sometimes one just needs to read a straight answer -and not several days of insisting- to realize that the request is just not right.  =D

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @chepner (thanks ), `__new__` should be used to create its own class or subclasses.  So tayloring it as a factory prompts for disaster.

While I felt my question taught me interesting stuff about `__new__`, `__init__` and even the 'object factory' model, I realize now that mixing the functionality came at a high price that doesn't cover the benefits.

My solution in the end was to use specific methods for the factory functionality.

```py
class SuperClass(): 
  ...
  @classmethod
  def create(cls, subtype, **kwargs): 
    if subtype in cls.valid_subtypes: 
      return cls.valid_subtypes[subtype](**kwargs)
    else: 
      msg = f"subtype '{subtype}' is not available for SuperClass factory."
      raise ValueError(msg)


  @classmethod
  def add_subtype(cls, key, a_Subclass): 
    cls.valid_subtypes[key] = a_Subclass

  @classmethod
  def update_subtypes(cls, subtypes_dict): 
    cls.valid_subtypes.update(subtypes_dict)
```

And this allows one to create the methods in either two ways:

```py
a1_obj = ClassA()
b1_obj = ClassB('hello b')

a2_obj = SuperClass.create('a')
b2_obj = SuperClass.create('b', 'hello b')
```

So yes.  I ~made peace~ accept adding the classmethod `create` in order to use the factory part.  =D
Regards!